# I am running spark 3.4.0 on k8s, how to save logs of executor pods?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

When running spark 3.4.0 on k8s using the native support, the pods of executors are deleted after the application ends, so it is hard to read their logs.

Is there some way to save logs of executor pods ?
Or Is there some way to prevent executor pods from being deleted (e.g., make the status completed) after the application ends ?

Comment: I mean the executor pods exits normally, no error occurs, I just want to know the normal log to extract information such as task execution time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an approach to avoid deleting pods.
Add the following in the command:

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination=false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).